# RequireJS in node failing for plugin-using dependencies (eg with use.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

In order to share AMD modules between the browser and node, I'm using RequireJS in both places (see [RequireJS in Node](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html)).

server/dataDao.js:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
var dataDao = module.exports = {};

requirejs(['client/resource'], function (Resource) {
   ...
});
```

client/resource.js:

```
define(['underscore'], function (_) {
  ...
});
```

This has generally been working ok, as long as the shared module does not involve any dependencies that don't work on the server.

I would like to introduce [use.js](https://github.com/tbranyen/use.js), however, to avoid manually wrapping non-AMD compatible libs like underscore. To do so, I have to prefix listed dependencies with `use!` (to trigger the use plugin in RequireJS).

client/resource.js:

```
define(['use!underscore'], function (_) {
  ...
});
```

This works well in the browser, but causes errors in Node:

```
Error: Calling node's require("use") failed with error: Error: Cannot find module 'use'
```

I believe this is not specific to the use plugin, but also text etc.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: What;s your config look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [version 0.3 of use](https://github.com/tbranyen/use.js/commit/e57b948e6856058501ca5804c14b856c42b80e12) I was able to get it working in node. Per the comment on your question, it may be a configuration issue -- it took me a couple of tries to get the pathing right.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed a pathing issue. And then I ran into the use.js bug, so I had to patch that. Glad to see 0.3 of use.js includes node support.